# Magento2: How to create deal of the day for specific product

Tags: magento2

I copy block code Deal of the day and added to page "Value of the day".

```
<p>{{block class="MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products\Deals" mgs_panel_title="" mgs_panel_note="" limit="1" perrow="1" ratio="7" category_ids="149" use_slider="0" loadmore="0" template="products/deals/grid.phtml"}}</p>
```

Now display all products deal of the day from category id 149.

But how to display specific product eg. with product ID 2273

grid.phtml

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getDealsByCategories($this->getCategoryIds()) ?>
<?php $themeHelper = $this->helper('MGS\Mpanel\Helper\Data'); ?>

<?php $lazyLoad = $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mgstheme/general/lazy_load'); ?>
<?php $baseImage = $this->getViewFileUrl('MGS_Mpanel::images/blank.png'); ?>
<?php $baseImageHover = $this->getViewFileUrl('MGS_Mpanel::images/blank.png'); ?>

<div class="content-block deal-product-cat-block">
    <?php if($this->getData('mgs_panel_title') != "" || $this->getData('mgs_panel_note') != ""): ?>
        <div class="content-heading">
            <?php if($this->getData('mgs_panel_title')): ?>
                <h3 class="title"><?php echo $themeHelper->decodeHtmlTag($this->getData('mgs_panel_title')) ?></h3>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if($this->getData('mgs_panel_note')): ?>
                <div class="block-note"><?php echo $themeHelper->decodeHtmlTag($this->getData('mgs_panel_note')) ?></div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if (count($_productCollection)>0): ?>

        <?php 
            $blockId = rand() . time();
            $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
            $useSlider = $this->getUseSlider();
            $perRow = $this->getPerrow();
            if($useSlider && $this->hasData('number_row') && $this->getNumberRow()>1){
                $columnCount = $perRow * $this->getNumberRow();
            }
            $image = 'category_page_grid';
            $_image = 'product_thumbnail_image';
            $size = $themeHelper->getImageSize($this->getRatio());
            $themeSettings = $themeHelper->getThemeSettings();
            $padding = $themeHelper->getImagePadding($this->getRatio());
            $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
            $col = $themeHelper->convertPerRowtoCol($perRow);
            $autoPlay = $this->getAutoplay() ? 'true' : 'false';
            $stopAuto = $this->getStopAuto() ? 'true' : 'false';
            $nav = $this->getNavigation() ? 'true' : 'false';
            $dot = $this->getPagination() ? 'true' : 'false';
        ?>

        <div class="block widget mgs-products deal-products-grid products-grid<?php if($useSlider): ?> row<?php if($this->getNumberRow() == 1): ?> slider-1-row<?php endif ?><?php endif ?>">
            <div class="items<?php if($useSlider): ?> owl-carousel<?php else: ?> row <?php echo $themeHelper->convertColClass($col, 'row') ?><?php endif ?>" id="deal-products<?php echo $blockId; ?>">
                <?php $i=0; $j=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++; ?>
                    <?php if($useSlider && $this->hasData('number_row') && $this->getNumberRow()>1): ?>
                        <?php if ($j++ % $columnCount == 0): ?>
                            <div class="item">
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="<?php if(!$useSlider || $this->getNumberRow()==1): ?>item <?php else: ?><?php echo $themeHelper->getClearClass($perRow, $i) ?> <?php echo $themeHelper->convertColClass($col, 'col') ?> <?php endif ?>product product-item<?php if(!$useSlider): ?> <?php echo $themeHelper->getClearClass($perRow, $i) ?> <?php echo $themeHelper->convertColClass($col, 'col') ?><?php endif ?>">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                            <?php
                                $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
                                $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $image)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl();
                                $productImageHover = $_imagehelper->init($_product, $_image)->resize($size['width'], $size['height'])->getUrl();
                                if(!$lazyLoad){
                                    $baseImage = $productImage;
                                    $baseImageHover = $productImageHover;
                                }
                            ?>
                            <div class="product-top">
                                <?php // Product Image ?>
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" style="padding-top: <?php echo $padding; ?>;" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $baseImage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive product-image-photo img-thumbnail<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> <?php if($useSlider): ?>owl-<?php endif ?>lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImage ?>"/>

                                    <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) !=  'no_selection'): ?>
                                        <?php if(basename($_product->getData('thumbnail')) != basename($_product->getData('small_image'))): ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $baseImageHover ?>" alt="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="img-responsive img-hover-show<?php if($lazyLoad): ?> <?php if($useSlider): ?>owl-<?php endif ?>lazy<?php endif ?>" data-src="<?php echo $productImageHover ?>"/>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <div class="product-image-photo"></div>
                                </a>

                                <?php echo $themeHelper->getProductLabel($_product) ?>

                                <ul class="actions-link">
                                    <li class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                        <?php $quickViewHelper = $this->helper('MGS\QuickView\Helper\Data'); ?>
                                        <?php echo $quickViewHelper->aroundQuickViewHtml($_product); ?>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && !$themeSettings['catalog']['wishlist_button']): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <button class="action towishlist"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-title="<?php echo __('Add to Wish List') ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                               data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                               role="button">
                                                <i class="pe-7s-like"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare'); ?>
                                    <?php if(!$themeSettings['catalog']['compare_button']): ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <button class="action tocompare"
                                               title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                               data-title="<?php echo __('Add to Compare') ?>"
                                               aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                               data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                               role="button">
                                                <i class="pe-7s-graph3"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </ul>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data']['uenc'], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
                                            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
                                            <button class="action tocart btn-cart" type="submit" data-title="<?php echo __('Add to Cart') ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products\Deals')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('MGS_Mpanel::products/deals/item.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
                                    <h5 class="product name product-item-name">
                                        <a class="product-item-link"
                                           href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h5>

                                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if($useSlider && $this->hasData('number_row') && $this->getNumberRow()>1): ?>
                        <?php if ($j % $columnCount == 0 || $j == count($_productCollection)): ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if($useSlider): ?>
                <?php if($this->hasData('number_row') && $this->getNumberRow()>1):?>
                    <?php $perRow = 1; ?>
                <?php endif ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    require([
                        'jquery',
                        'mgs/owlcarousel'
                    ], function ($) {
                        $('#deal-products<?php echo $blockId ?>').owlCarousel({
                            items: <?php echo $perRow; ?>,
                            autoplay: <?php echo $autoPlay ?>,
                            loop: false,
                            <?php if($lazyLoad): ?>lazyLoad: true,<?php endif ?>
                            autoplayHoverPause: <?php echo $stopAuto ?>,
                            nav: <?php echo $nav ?>,
                            dots: <?php echo $dot ?>,
                            navText: ["<i class='pe-7s-angle-left'></i>","<i class='pe-7s-angle-right'></i>"],
                            <?php if(!$this->hasData('number_row') || $this->getNumberRow()==1):?>
                                responsive:{
                                    0:{
                                        items:1
                                    },
                                    768:{
                                        items:2
                                    },
                                    992:{
                                        items:<?php echo $perRow; ?>
                                    }
                                }
                            <?php endif ?>
                        });
                    });
                </script>

            <?php endif ?>
        </div>  
    <?php else: ?>
        <div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning"><?php echo __('There are no deals matching the selection.') ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

deals.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
/**
 * Main contact form block
 */
class Deals extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_count;

    protected $_date;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $urlHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->_date = $date;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getModel($model){
        return $this->_objectManager->create($model);
    }

    /**
     * Product collection initialize process
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection|Object|\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection($category)
    {
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        if($category->getId()){
            $categoryIdArray = [$category->getId()];
            $categoryFilter = ['eq'=>$categoryIdArray];
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter($categoryFilter);
        }

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['image', 'name', 'short_description'])
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', ['notnull'=>true]);

        $collection->getSelect()->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');

        $collection->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getDealsByCategories($categoryIds){
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        if($categoryIds!=''){
            $categoryIdArray = explode(',',$categoryIds);
            if(count($categoryIdArray)>0){
                $categoryFilter = ['eq'=>$categoryIdArray];
                $collection->addCategoriesFilter($categoryFilter);
            }
        }

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addAttributeToSelect(['image', 'name', 'short_description'])
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', ['notnull'=>true]);

        $collection->getSelect()->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');

        $collection->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getAllProductCount(){
        //return $this->_count;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('limit')) {
            return parent::getProductsCount();
        }
        return $this->getData('limit');
    }

    public function getCurrentPage(){
        if ($this->getCurPage()) {
            return $this->getCurPage();
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public function getProductsPerRow(){
        if ($this->hasData('per_row')) {
            return $this->getData('per_row');
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getCustomClass(){
        if ($this->hasData('custom_class')) {
            return $this->getData('custom_class');
        }
    }

    public function getCurrentDate(){
        return $this->_date->gmtDate();
    }

    public function getAddToCartPostParams(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED =>
                    $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($url),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get form key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormKey()
    {
        return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
    }

    public function getCategoryByIds(){
        $result = [];
        if($this->hasData('category_ids')){
            $categoryIds = $this->getData('category_ids');
            $categoryArray = explode(',',$categoryIds);
            if(count($categoryArray)>0){
                foreach($categoryArray as $categoryId){
                    $category = $this->getModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
                    if($category->getId()){
                        $result[] = $category;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of `MGS\Mpanel\Block\Products\Deal` and `products/deals/grid.phtml`

Comment: Amit Bere, topic are updated